# Flexnav Color Change

Tags: javascript, css, colors, flexnav

I'm using flexnav for a top menu bar and I can't seem to change the color of anything.  I'd like to have a different background color, but no matter what I change in the css the appearance of the flexnav bar stays the same.  It's a pretty generic grey-black with a darker black for hover items.  I've changed the color setting for the menu buttons, the border, etc. but nothing seems to make a difference.
Is there some js that is overwriting the css maybe?  I can't find the problem.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Try sharing some code of what you have tried and where you think the problem could be.

Comment: Probably not, you are doing the override in the right order?
Your declaration should be executed after the plugin declaration.